# Relationship between Gumbel and Weibull distribution, accelerated failure time models, and Survreg using R

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution, gumbel-distribution

I have three questions concerning accelerated failure time models (AFT), one statistical, one regarding how to implement these models in R, and one related to finding out information about what R is doing. In short my questions are;

1) What is the relationship between the Gumbel and Weibull distributions?

2) How can I use (1) to simulate a AFT model using Gumbel errors and fit this model in R?

3) Where can I find formulae regarding exactly what distribution specification R is using when fitting a Weibull distribution, and exactly what model is being fitted?

I am having difficulties implementing 2), which may be due to my mis-understanding of 1), but which I can't seem to resolve due to 3). Question (3) is self-explanatory but (2) and (3) require more detail;

1) It seems a standard result that if $U\sim Gumbel(\alpha,\beta)$ then $V:=\exp(U)\sim Weibull(\lambda,\sigma)$ where $\alpha=\log(\sigma)$ and $\beta=1/\lambda$. However using the definition of the Gumbel and Weibull distributions commonly used (for example Wikipedia), when I do the derivation I can only get the transformation $V':=1/\exp(U)$ to give this result but where $\alpha=-\log(\sigma)=\log(1/\sigma)$. Thus can anyone confirm or not any knowledge of this relationship, or perhaps suggest where I have gone wrong (for brevity in the first instance I do not supply the detail)?

2) My approach is to use

$Y_{i}:=\log\left(\frac{1}{T_{i}}\right)=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + e_{i},\hspace{20pt}i=1,...,N$,

as a data-generating mechanism for the logarithm of the time to event where $e_{i}\sim Gumbel(\alpha,\beta)$, where $i$ indexes subjects, $x_{i}$ is a scalar covariate, and the $e_{i}$ are all independent. I choose $\alpha=-\beta*c$ where $c$ is Euler's constant in order to ensure $E[e_{i}]=\alpha+c\beta=0$. This gives

$Y_{i}\sim Gumbel(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i}+\alpha,\beta)$,

and using (1)

$T_{i}\sim Weibull(1/\beta,\exp[-(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i}+\alpha)])$

The code at the end of this post is a minimal working example of this approach, where I censor subjects if $T_{i}$ is greater than the median of the $N$ theoretical medians of $\{T_{1},...,T_{N}\}$, and create an event if not. This gives $50-60\%$ of subjects being censored, the balance having events, and I interpret this to be right-censoring (say the end of a study).

I then use the survreg package in R to try to fit an AFT to $Y_{i}$ using the "dist=weibull" option. Using $\beta_{0}=-10$ and $\beta_{1}=0$ gives the following output

[image]

which gives the intercept being positive when it should be negative. Things get worse when using $\beta_{0}=-10$ and $\beta_{1}=2$ which gives the following output

[image]

which is obviously wrong. Thus I would like to know what model I am actually fitting when using the survreg package.

The code below is a minimal working example (apart from some code to produce plots which can be helpful).

```
# minimal working example
set.seed(123)
require(survival)
#params of the gumbel(alpha_gum,beta_gum) distribution so that E[X]=0
beta_gum = 1/5 #
alpha_gum = -(beta_gum*(-digamma(1)))

#calc the mean of the errors using Eulers constant as the negative of the diagamma function
mu_e = alpha_gum + (beta_gum*(-digamma(1)))#should be 0   

# regression parameters
intercept = -10;
beta1 =0;
#beta1 =2;

#number of subjects
N=1000;

# vector of uniform random numbers
U = runif(N)

#vector for gumbel distributed errors
e = matrix(,nrow=N,ncol=1)


# log of time to event, time to event, mean LTTE
logTTE = matrix(,nrow=N,ncol=1)
Xbeta_LTTE= matrix(,nrow=N,ncol=1)
TTE = matrix(,nrow=N,ncol=1)
TTE2 = matrix(,nrow=N,ncol=1)

#censoring variable
censor = matrix(,nrow=N,ncol=1)

#simulate covariate from a normal distribution
covariate1 = rnorm(N,6,4)

for (i in 1:N)
{
  # calculate the Gumbel RV from the inverse CDF of the Gumbel
  e[i,1] = alpha_gum + (-beta_gum*log(-log(U[i])))

  #generate the mean log TTE  
  Xbeta_LTTE[i,1] = intercept + (beta1*covariate1[i])

  #add the errors
  logTTE[i,1] = Xbeta_LTTE[i,1] + e[i,1]  

  #transform to raw time variable - this is a Weibull dist
  #TTE_i ~ Weibull[1/beta_gum , exp(-[logTTE_i+alpha_gum])
  TTE[i,1] = 1/exp(logTTE[i,1])      
}

#calc the median the TTE given TTE ~ Weibull[1/beta_gum , exp(-[X_i^t*beta+alpha_gum])
lambda_array = exp(-(Xbeta_LTTE + alpha_gum + (beta_gum*(-digamma(1)))))
kappa = 1/beta_gum
median_TTE_array = (lambda_array)*(log(2)^(1/kappa))
median_TTE = median(median_TTE_array)

# calculate the censoring variable
for (i in 1:N)
{
  #censoring: subjects with a TTE >median_TTE will be right-censored
  #i.e. study ends at T=median_TTE say
  if (TTE[i,1]>median_TTE)
  {
    censor[i,1]=1 
    TTE2[i,1]=median_TTE
  }
  else
  {
    censor[i,1]=0    
    TTE2[i,1]=TTE[i,1]
  }  
}

#calculate the percentage of censored subjects and do a plot
pc_censored = sum(censor)/N

#fit AFT model
datframe_surv = data.frame(covariate1)
attach(datframe_surv)

m.surv = Surv(TTE2,censor,type="right")
m.surv.fit = survreg(m.surv~covariate1,dist="weibull",scale=1)
sum = summary(m.surv.fit)
print(sum)



###################  plots ########################


#histogram of the errors - gumbel dist
h1 = hist(e, breaks=50, plot=FALSE) 

#histogram of the mean log TTE - gumbel dist
h2 = hist(logTTE, breaks=50, plot=FALSE) 

#histogram of the fixed means
h3 = hist(Xbeta_LTTE, breaks=50, plot=FALSE) 

#histogram of the TTE - weibul dist
h4 = hist(TTE, breaks=50, plot=FALSE) 

#calc the mean of the log TTE given logTTE ~ Gumbel(X_i^t*beta+alpha_gum,beta_gum)
median_logTTE_array = Xbeta_LTTE + alpha_gum - (beta_gum*(log(log(2))))
median_logTTE = median(median_logTTE_array)



#calc the means
ylim_h1 = c(min(h1$density),max(h1$density) )
xlim_h1 = c(mu_e,mu_e )

ylim_h2 = c(min(h3$density),max(h3$density) )
xlim_h2 = c(median_logTTE,median_logTTE )

ylim_h3 = c(min(h3$density),max(h3$density) )
xlim_h3 = c(mean(Xbeta_LTTE),mean(Xbeta_LTTE) )


ylim_h4 = c(min(h4$density),max(h4$density) )
xlim_h4 = c(median_TTE,median_TTE )


#dev.off()
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

plot(h1$mids,h1$density,col='red',main="errors - gumbel dist",xlab="errors (log time)")
lines(xlim_h1,ylim_h1)

plot(h3$mids,h3$density,col='red',main="mean log TTE (X*beta) - fixed",xlab="mean log TTE (log time)")
lines(xlim_h3,ylim_h3)

plot(h2$mids,h2$density,col='red',main="log TTE - gumbel dist",xlab="log TTE (log time)")
lines(xlim_h2,ylim_h2)


plot(h4$mids,h4$density,col='red',main="TTE - Weibull dist",xlab="TTE (time)")
lines(xlim_h4,ylim_h4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion comes from competing definitions of "Gumbel distribution" and competing parameterizations of the Weibull distribution.

**(1) It might be best to avoid the term "Gumbel distribution" because it has different interpretations.**

One is a *maximum* extreme value distribution, the definition used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution). "*This article uses the Gumbel distribution to model the distribution of the maximum value.*" (Emphasis in original.)

Another is a *minimum* extreme value distribution, the definition provided by [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GumbelDistribution.html). "*In this work, the term 'Gumbel distribution' is used to refer to the distribution corresponding to a minimum extreme value distribution.*" (Emphasis added.) That is used by *Mathematica* for its `GumbelDistribution`, which calls the Wikipedia maximum extreme value version the `ExtremeValueDistribution.`

**It's the *minimum* extreme value version that provides the "standard result" for the association between Weibull and Gumbel distributions.** As you used the *maximum* extreme value version, you got the result that you found.

**(2) Continuing from point (1), to make this work you have to alter (a) the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to get a mean of 0, and (b) the CDF to match the *minimum* extreme value Gumbel.**

(a) The mean of the *minimum* extreme value version is $\alpha - \gamma \beta$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's gamma, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as represented in the question. That's different from  $\alpha + \gamma \beta$ for the *maximum* extreme value version, as used in the question.

(b) The $q$th quantile (inverse CDF) of the *minimum* extreme value version is:

$$\alpha +\beta  \log (-\log (1-q)).$$

The inverse CDF used in the question's code is for the *maximum* extreme value version.

I haven't yet done those replacements in the code, but I suspect that (absent other problems) all with then be OK.

**(3) The question of "exactly what distribution specification R is using when fitting a Weibull distribution" is not well specified.**

R packages can differ in parameterizations, and the same function might use different parameterizations depending on the arguments in the function call. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/508252/28500) provides some examples. Notably, as the manual page for the `survreg()` function in the [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) explains:

> There are multiple ways to parameterize a Weibull distribution. The `survreg` function embeds it in a general location-scale family, which is a different parameterization than the `rweibull` function, and often leads to confusion.

```
survreg's scale  =    1/(rweibull shape)
survreg's intercept = log(rweibull scale)
```

I don't see any way around these types of confusions, except to be extremely careful in reading specific definitions and manual pages.

Comment: Many thanks EdM for this answer! The question is old but your answer still very informative and useful.

Comment: @dandar your question was the highest-voted unanswered question about `survival` on this site, so I thought that it deserved some attention. I learned a lot myself in the process.

Comment: Amazing! I totally forgot about this. Thank you for taking the time to answer it.