# Reconciling AFT Model Output With AFT Theory (Survival Analysis)

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, survival

TLDR: I have spent quite a lot of time trying to reconcile the output of AFT regression libraries with the expected outputs from the theory. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Suppose you are using a Weibull AFT (Accelerated Failure Time) Regression Model i.e. given survival time $T$, suppose we have observed values of covariates $x_{i1}, ..., x_{ip}$ and possibly censored survival time $t_i$, then the Weibull AFT model is:
$$ log(t_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + ... + \beta_p x_{ip}+ \sigma \epsilon_i  $$

For $i = 1, 2, ..., n$ samples. Where $\epsilon_i$ are IID according to a Gumbel (Extreme Value Type 1) distribution, $\sigma$ is a scale parameter etc.

Then it follows that the pdf for $T$ is given by:

[image]

Where the PDF of the Weibull distribution is given as:

[image]

I.e. if we let shape $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sigma}$ and scale $\rho = exp(x\beta)$ then we see $T \sim W(exp(x\beta), \frac{1}{\sigma})$.

My question is about the results from AFT libraries in R (e.g. `aftreg` or `flexsurv`) - the results are similar from both libraries. An example model fit output is given below - in this example you have two features in the model (TDC1 is time dependent covariate 1 coefficient and TDC2 is time dependent covariate 2 coefficient):

I.e. there are four parameters produced by the model: one for each of the input variables and a log(scale) and log(shape) parameter (baseline parameters apparently).

My questions are:

1. Why is there no estimate for $\sigma $ (only the baseline shape)?
2. Is it possible to reconstruct the pdf for $T$ (as above) using the four parameters estimated i.e. covariate coefficients and the baseline scale and shape?

See below for output from `eha` package (aftreg):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to answer this after researching.

There are multiple different parameterisations of Weibull that vary between packages and on Wikipedia (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/468333/28500 https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/508252/28500)

With regards to log(scale) and log(shape) from the results output of the `afreg` library from the `eha` as given in the question. The documentation from the `eha` library states that the generic parameterisation for AFT survival regression is given by:
$$S(t, a, b, \beta, z) = S_0\left( \left( \frac{t}{exp(b + z\beta)} \right)^{exp(a)}  \right) $$

Where $S_0$ is a standardised survivor function. Where baseline parameters $a$ and $b$ are given by:

- $a = log(shape)$
- $b = log(scale)$

For Survival Modelling of Weibull AFT we have the following form of the standardised survival function, with shape and scale:
$$S_0(t) = exp \left(-\left(\frac{t}{scale} \right)^{shape} \right) =  exp \left(-\left(\frac{t}{exp(b)} \right)^{exp(a)} \right)$$

For different populations we have that (by definition of an AFT):

$$ S(t) = S_0\left( \frac{t}{\lambda(x)} \right) = S_0\left( \frac{t}{exp(z \beta)} \right)$$

Therefore:
$$ S(t) =  exp \left(-\left(\frac{t}{exp(b) exp(z\beta)} \right)^{exp(a)} \right) =  exp \left(-\left(\frac{t}{exp(b + z\beta)} \right)^{exp(a)} \right)$$

So how does this help us reconcile with other parameterisations of Weibull (in particular that from Wikipedia)? For example, the following Weibull parameterisation $T \sim W(\rho, \gamma)$ with PDF:

$$ f_T(t; \rho, \gamma) = F'(t; \rho, \gamma) = \frac{\gamma}{\rho} \left( \frac{\gamma}{\rho} \right)^{\gamma - 1}exp \left( -(\frac{t}{\rho})^{\gamma} \right)  $$

Where $\gamma$ is the scale and $\rho$ is the shape. Therefore under this parameterisation:

$$S_T(t) = 1 - F_T(t) = exp \left( -(\frac{t}{\rho})^{\gamma} \right) $$

So in order to link the two parameterisations: $\gamma = exp(a) = \frac{1}{\sigma}$ and $\rho = exp(b + z\beta)$ i.e. $T \sim W(exp(b + z\beta), \frac{1}{\sigma})$ within the `eha` package. Therefore to answer my question above, it is possible to reconstruct the pdf for T with the four parameters provided by the `eha` package.

Answer (score 1):

The `shape` parameter corresponds to the parameter you have identified as $\sigma$ (after skimming the `flexsurv` [paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v070i08) for 2 min)

Comment: So you are suggesting that the baseline parameter log(shape) [returned in the results example above] is equal to the shape parameter from the Weibull PDF? Is this not the baseline shape?

Comment: related to, read their paper and docs to figure out what the parameters correspond to in your parameterization.

Comment: @MikeTauber the competing parameterizations of the Weibull are confusing. See for example [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/468333/28500) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/508252/28500) for examples of how that differs among packages and sometimes is somewhat inconsistent even within a package. Even though I wrote those answers, I find myself re-learning almost from scratch every time I come back to Weibull.

Comment: Thanks @EdM this is most useful. Have you ever come across the library 'eha' and aftreg? Do you know what Weibull parameterisation is used in eha ? (see in post - trying to understand baseline parameters log(shape) and log(scale)) in relation to survreg also.

Comment: (See below - I linked the two)