# Simulate a Weibull regression model

Tags: survival, simulation, accelerated-failure-time

I am trying to simulate a AFT Weibull model in R using a log-linear model

\begin{align}
log(Y)=\beta_0 +\beta_1 X1+\beta_2 X2+c W
\end{align}
where $W ~$ a extreme value distribution. below is my simulation code:

```
install.packages("extRemes")
library(extRemes)

n<-500000    
x1<-rnorm(n,0,1)    
x2<-rnorm(n,0,1)    
error<-revd(n, loc = 0, scale = 1)    
b0<- 1    
b1<-0.5    
b2<--1.2    
c<-1    
time<-exp(b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+c*error)    
status<-rep(1,n)    
survreg(Surv(time, status==1) ~ x1+x2,dist="exponential")

####output 

Coefficients:    
(Intercept)          x1          x2 

  2.9390956   0.4931199  -1.2061369 

Scale fixed at 1 
#####
```

I can not understand why intercept is 2.94, not close to 1 ?

Thanks for the help from EDM. R Gumbel and extreme value functions are all for maximum extreme value distribution

\begin{align}
f(x)=e^{(-x-e^{-x})}
\end{align}

What we really need is a random variable from the minimum extreme value distribution with density function like this
\begin{align}
f(x)=e^{(x-e^{x})}
\end{align}

Once I generate the error from a maximum extreme value distribution, I need to set it to -1*error.

```
n<-500000    
x1<-rnorm(n,0,1)    
x2<-rnorm(n,0,1)    
error<-revd(n, loc = 0, scale = 1)    
b0<- 1    
b1<-0.5    
b2<--1.2    
c<-1    
time<-exp(b0+b1*x1+b2*x2-c*error)    
status<-rep(1,n)    
survreg(Surv(time, status==1) ~ x1+x2,dist="exponential")


Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
   1.000095    0.500679   -1.200210 

Scale fixed at 1
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to match your model: in particular, why do you exponentiate the linear combination to create `time`?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually log(Y)

Comment: Please edit the question to specify which extreme value distribution parameterization you are using and the package from which you get `revd()`, as that function doesn't seem to be in base R. There's both a maximum and a minimum extreme value distribution; make sure you're using the correct one.

Comment: I tried different extreme value functions or gumbel function. I have the same issue. I found out the issues with intercept only happen with extreme value distribution. If I specify W to be a normal or logistic, the intercept estimates are close to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this formulation of a Weibull model requires use of the *minimum* extreme value distribution for $W$. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/539885/28500) explains the difficulty of assuming that a "Gumbel distribution" or "extreme value distribution" is what you need without further specification.

For a location of 0, a scale of 1, and a shape of 0, the code for the `revd()` function you used, or for the similar `rgev()` function in the R `evd` package, is equivalent to `-log(rexp(n))`, where `rexp(n)` represents `n` random samples from a standard exponential distribution. That returns random samples from the standard *maximum* extreme value distribution, the form used by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution):

> This article uses the Gumbel distribution to model the distribution of the maximum value. To model the minimum value, use the negative of the original values.

As `exp(-x) = 1/exp(x)`, you can use `-log(1/rexp(n)) = log(rexp(n))` (or just multiply all the values you got from the maximum extreme value distribution by $-1$) to get samples from the standard *minimum* extreme value distribution.

A quick illustration without covariates, intercept-only model, starting with a sample from the standard maximum extreme value distribution as you used:

```
set.seed(202)
maxEV1000 <- -log(rexp(1000)) ## what you used, for maximum EV
survreg(Surv(exp(maxEV1000))~1,dist="exponential")
# Call:
# survreg(formula = Surv(exp(maxEV1000)) ~ 1, dist = "exponential")
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept) 
#    2.039815 
# 
# Scale fixed at 1 
# 
# Loglik(model)= -3039.8   Loglik(intercept only)= -3039.8
# n= 1000
```

That gives a positive intercept similar to what you found for the excess intercept over what you had intended in your simulation. If you instead work with samples from the standard *minimum* extreme value distribution:

```
minEV1000 <- -maxEV1000      ## what you need, for minimum EV
survreg(Surv(exp(minEV1000))~1,dist="exponential")
# Call:
# survreg(formula = Surv(exp(minEV1000)) ~ 1, dist = "exponential")
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept) 
# -0.01854772 
# 
# Scale fixed at 1 
# 
# Loglik(model)= -981.5   Loglik(intercept only)= -981.5
# n= 1000
```

you get what you expect, an intercept near 0. If you don't specify an exponential model and allow a general Weibull fit, you get the correct scale (1.005) from this latter data sample, versus 1.653 when you try to fit the former data sample.

Comment: thanks. R functions have different definitions of extreme value distribution. As you said, they are for maximum extreme value distribution, not minimum extreme value distribution. I just can not understand why they can not standardize the definitions

Comment: @Vincent it’s maybe even worse for Weibull. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/508139/28500), for example. The same words can be used to describe fundamentally different parameters, and you always have to check which parameterization is used. I still get confused every time I need to deal with Gumbel or Weibull.